# Adding an onclick function to a form button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using a Wordpress plugin to create a form and unfortunately the plugin doesn't allow to add onClick code and I would like to use Google Event Tracking to perform analytics on the form. What Javascript would I need to be able to add this:

```
onClick="_trackEvent ('Home', 'ButtonClick', 'Submit')"
```

To my form button? The ID of the form button is `ninja_forms_field_10`

Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would need to be something like this (using jQuery since it is built in to Wordpress by default):

```
$('#ninja_forms_field_10').click(function() { _trackEvent('Home','ButtonClick','Submit'); });
```

Since you need to pass parameters to the function you need to call, you have to wrap it in another function which will then call it.